# How to generate a Raster(Tiff) from XYZ ungridded dem in c++?

Tags: c++, geospatial, interpolation, raster, elevation

Hei, 
I am using gdal for reading raster sources but unfortunately it only supports gridded xyz dem(doesnt support ungridded xyz dem). So i am trying to create a raster image from xyz ungridded dem so it can be read by gdal. I have already created triangles from the points using s_hull. But now i am confused how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using gdal_grid.

Comment: I tried but it didnt help much. The geometry is altered.

Comment: I already have the Mesh(in geographical coordinates) which i generated using collision. I tried taking min and max of bbox of mesh and making width & height by subtracting max-min and then querying for height on all the vertices in the mesh. But it works only if they are in geographical cordinate system n not lat-long as then it can be really tiny. Any ideas how to do it ? Thanks in advance.